# Suggesting new terminal commands

Tags: debian, terminal, python, command

What is the way of suggesting/writing new Linux terminal commands to be added to the set of a specific linux (for instance if one thinks some commands could be useful for other users as well)? Is it viable for users not in the development team of a Linux distributaion to suggest/post their code somewhere for approval and integration as for next releases?

Comment: Write the command, share it, use it! There are a tons of commands at [github](http://github.com/) already.

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr/local/` and specifically in your case, the `/usr/local/bin/`  (often in `$PATH` by default) is made for this purpose: you can put your application there and it will appear/be used like any other "terminal" commands.

When it is polished enough and you want to conquer the world, you may wish to try packaging it for various distributions (RedHat, Debian, LinuxMint, etc.).

There is no universal set of "terminal commands" in the Linux world (it is different in other worlds, like in *BSD): besides a basic core, all other commands are typically installed through distribution packages, one package per command (in a simplified version).

It is up to each distribution to decide what application are packaged, and how/if they are considered standard and installed by default or not.

So after having packaged yours and/or convinced someone to package it for you you can try making sure it is included in various distributions.

You could also just distribute it yourself, but of course the problem will be to advertise the whole world about its existence. Starting with a webpage about it should be a good idea.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, this falls in my "convinced someone to package it" :-)

Comment: Crud, my eyes skipped that bit.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you for your answer. I have my own commands in my **$HOME/bin/**. What i meant was actually for some commands to be integrated in a specific distribution (which you also answered :-)